# Doing A GET request in CodeIgniter using URI Segments

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

If I have a form like this:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
</form>
```

and if I Submit it, it generates a URL like this: 
`http://exmaple.com/search/results?search=text1+text2`
Now this doesn't work with my code. How do I make it use URI Segments, so the generated url looks like this: `http://exmaple.com/search/results/search/text1+text2`

**More Clarification**
In other words, What I want is that when I do a get request using a simple html form, the url it generates look like the codeigniter's URL i.e 
`example.com/class/function/param1/param2` 
and not 
`example.com/class/function?param1&param2`

Comment: have you tried using routes in codeigniter? `http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html`

Comment: well i just tried adding this route: `$route['search/results?search=(:any)'] = "search/results/search/$1";` but it doesn't work

Comment: Try this `$route['search/results/search/(:any)'] = "search/results?search=$1"` you switched them..

Answer (score 0):

Using codeigniter routing you can achieve `http://exmaple.com/search/results/search/text1+text2`

by using putting this in your route

```
$route['search/results/search/(:any)'] = "search/results?search=$1"
```

Comment: I think you have miss understood my problem. What I want is that when I do a get request using a simple html form, the url it generates look like the codeigniter's URL i.e `example.com/class/function/param1/param2` and not `example.com/class/function?param1&param2

Answer (score 0):

```
in your codeigniter config file $config['enable_query_strings'] is set to false, so the url looks like http://example.com/search/results/search/text1+text2

if you want url like http://example.com/search/resutls?search=text1+text2 then set $config['enable_query_strings'] to true;
```